# make button not clickable when click card

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How do I enter code here to make the button not clickable when clicking the card? I try to solve it but I'm new to vue js. Any help?

```html
<vs-row>
    <vs-col v-for="patient in patients" type="flex" vs-justify="center" vs-align="center" vs-w="3">
        <router-link :to="`/patient-information/${patient.id}`">
        <vs-card actionable>
        <div slot="header" class="txt-center">

            <vs-avatar class="text-vt " v-bind:text="patient.firstname.charAt(0)"/>
            <h3 class="align-ct link">
                {{ patient.firstname }} {{  patient.lastname }}
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="txt-center link">
            <span><h4>{{ patient.age }} years old {{ patient.gender }}</h4></span>
        </div>
        <div slot="footer" class="btn-index">
            <vs-row vs-justify="flex-end">
            <vs-button class="btn-index" @click="editPatient(patient.id)" color="orange" color-text="rgb(50,50,50)" icon="create"></vs-button>
            <vs-button class="btn-index" @click="deletePatient(patient)" type="gradient" color="danger" icon="delete"></vs-button>
            </vs-row>
        </div>
        </vs-card>
        </router-link>
    </vs-col>
</vs-row>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean exactly. _"make the button not clickable then clicking the card"_ doesn't make a lot of sense. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63733095/edit) and explain, in plain words, what you want to happen and when.

Comment: I got it wrong, I'm sorry, all I want to say is "make the button not clickable when clicking the card"

Comment: Again, that doesn't make a lot of sense. You can either click the card or the buttons. Could you please do as suggested and explain clearly what you want to happen. Write it out as a set of steps with actions, behaviours and results